# Chat message custom UI for each message

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I've been stuck on this for months and I don't know what to do or where to look to solve it If you guys could point me in the right direction...

Basically, I have a simple chat room that will only ever involve two people and whenever a user sends a message I get two values: their username and their message.

At the moment this is my code for showing each message:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);

        }
           messageView.append(chat_username + " - " + chat_msg + "\n");
    }
```

As you can see when I get both values I append them into a simple textView in a scrollView in the chat window. However, I don't want that. I want to make it a bit nicer than just simple text. I just don't know how to show that layout below in the link with the relevant data in it (username + message).

[Link to a picture that shows what layout I'd like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDcuC.png)

Hope I explained it well enough, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @Raj I didn't come to ask that whole question to receive 'add colour' to make it better. I mean how do I inflate that layout in the picture with the right data and show it in the chat window

Comment: Are u using recyclerView ?

Comment: @Raj I apparently need to use a List view and then every time someone sends a message inflate that layout into the listview? I just don't know how to